# Realigning a coordinate grid

Tags: math

I have a pretty simple grid in variables in my program.

The actual grid goes from 0 to 1 on each axis.

What I'd like is to essentially translate the origin to where -1,-1 is in my current setup. How can I change these axes mathematically to get rid of all negative numbers, have my origin at the bottom left, and have x and y range from 0 to 1?

Comment: -1 for the confusing image and not enough explanation in the original question. Please rephrase like this: I have a coordinate system where `x`-axis ranges from `-1` to `+1` and I want to convert the values to a system ranging from `0` to `...`. Similarly for the `y`-axis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each axis, add one and multiply by two. So,

```
x' = (x + 1)/2
y' = (y + 1)/2
```

- (0, 0) becomes (0.5, 0.5)
- (1, 1) stays (1, 1)
- (-1, -1) becomes (0, 0)

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks, this makes sense. It always makes sense _after_ the fact, of course ;)

Comment: Not a problem! Again, to be of the most use to future visitors, you should probably remove or edit the image above to actually reflect the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
x' = (x+5)/10
y' = (y+5)/10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. `(-1.0 + 5) / 10` does not equal zero, as it should. The bottom left corner at -1,-1 should be translated to 0,0 and the top right corner should be translated to 1,1.

Comment: Thanks, @Geoffroy, that was careless of me.

Comment: @TKKocheran, I misinterpreted "bottom left". Let's get this straight; you want to translate (-1,1) to (0,0) and (5,5) to (1,1), is that right?

Comment: No, ignore the image above. I have a grid where top right is -1,1, top left is 1,1, bottom left is 1,-1, and bottom right is -1,-1. Center of grid is at 0,0. I need to make -1,-1 == 0,0 and 1,1 still equal 1,1. I need to essentially get rid of all negative values and have the entire grid be based around the bottom left corner and extend from 0 to 1 on the x and y axes.

Comment: I think the image is doing more harm than good here - you may want to move your explanation here into the actual question.